# Replace only specified occurence in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Is there a way to replace specified occurence of a match?

I have a strings:

```
'1245'
'1 34 6'
'*-98 09'
```

And I only want to replace second and third digit with 'x', so the output will be:

```
'1xx5'
'1 xx 6'
'*-9x x9'
```

Is there such a function/way in php?

Comment: Iterate over each character and check if it's number

Answer (score 2):

You can search using this regex with 2 capture group. 1st group captures all the text before 2nd digit and second group captures text between 2nd and 3rd digits:

```
^(\D*\d\D*)\d(\D*)\d
```

replace it by:

```
$1x$2x
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/50XxeL/3)

**Code:**

```
$repl = preg_replace('/^(\D*\d\D*)\d(\D*)\d/m', '$1x$2x', $str);
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
^        # start
(        # start captured group #1
   \D*   # match 0 or more non-digits
   \d    # match 1st digit
   \D*   # match 0 or more non-digits
)        # end captured group #1
\d       # match 2nd digit
(        # start captured group #2
   \D*   # match 0 or more non-digits
)        # end captured group #2
\d       # match 3rd digit
```

Comment: I don't know if it could be a situation but if there are only 2 digits this won't replace the second, the string needs minimum 3 digits for this to work.

Comment: Since OP wrote **I only want to replace second and third digit** that means there must be at least 3 digits to get this replacement done.

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `preg_replace_callback` function:

```
$str = '*-98 09';
$count = 0;

$replaced = preg_replace_callback("/\d/", function ($m) use(&$count){
    return (++$count == 1)? $m[0] : 'x';  // replace excepting the first digit
}, $str, 3);

print_r($replaced);
```

The output:

```
"*-9x x9"
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Answer (score 1):

Another way using limit of [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and regex with a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
$str = ['1245', '1 34 6', '*-98 09'];
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=\d)\D*\K\d/', "x", $str, 2);
```

[See demo at eval.in  `print_r($str);`](https://eval.in/685984)

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1xx5
    [1] => 1 xx 6
    [2] => *-9x x9
)
```

- `(?<=\d)` looks behind if there is a digit.
- `\D*` matches any amount of non-digits.
- [`\K` resets](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) beginning of the  reported match.

This has the advantage of being easily extendable to more than two replacements.

Comment: Look at this demo: https://regex101.com/r/1DfrnK/1. The regex seems to eat more than necessary.

Comment: @bobble bubble ok and what with if I would like to match only first three digits from the end? F.e. input '-876 832 09' should become '-876 xxx 09'

Comment: @Stephan This is meant for use with limit on single line strings like [in the provided demo](https://eval.in/685984).

Comment: @user7201963 This is very different. You can try [like this](https://www.regex101.com/r/pG6tBc/1) (without the preg limit)

Comment: @bobble bubble is there a way to start counting a mtach from the end? Like - replace second and third digit, but from the end (right)?

Comment: @user7201963 [See like this demo](https://eval.in/686035). Or do you mean more generally? Afaik there is no paramater available for preg_replace to replace from right to left x occurences but why not ask another question (: